# Argument count for a string

Tags: string, matlab, error-handling

I have written an error case into my code, so when

```
if (condition 1)
     error('Error \n(error message)',0)
```

However, MatLab says 'The format string might not agree with the argument count'

I'm unsure why I get this message, the error message doesn't contain an argument count.

Comment: Please read up the documentation of a function before asking a question about it. Here is the same for `error` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/error.html#bumt6f4-4

Answer (score 2):

`error` behaves as `sprintf`.

Either use

```
error('Error \n(error message)');
```

or

```
error('Error %d \n(error message)',0)
```

I.e., you can introduce some format specifiers.